# Is REDSHIFT one word or two?

Tags: terminology

I (myself) prefer one but an editor I use redlines it as a misspelling, so which one should we use here?

Comment: You don't need quora, only a dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/redshift

Comment: @James K: Which one? Many spell it as 2 words, as does this editor and Quora's too, as does the European Space Agency/ESA.

Comment: I think it's rather normal for the English language, when two nouns are combined to form a new noun, to start out separated, then hyphenated, and finally conjoined. In addition to "red shift → red-shift → redshift", examples include "light year → light-year → lightyear", and also "minutes of arc → arc minute → arc-minute → arcmin", I think. "Light-seconds" are still hyphenated though, perhaps because it's not as popular a word.

Comment: It's your web browser that's doing the spell check, not Stack Exchange or Quora or the ESA website.

Comment: I think the question is OK. From time to time we have questions that ask to clarify certain items necessary to write or publish about Astronomy. See for example [How is the star 'Spica' pronounced?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/48596/7982) and [When we say a variable star is "fainting" does it mean something more or different than "dimming" or "fading"?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34547/7982) At only 3.6 questions per day, it's not like we're so overwhelmed that we need to split hairs on topicality. After all, this has a well-defined, and it turns out *interesting* answer!

Comment: And that answer is fact-based, so closing for "This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts " seems pointless. **voting to leave open**

Comment: I've rolled back the edits.  Please don't use edit to ask more questions.  If you want to know how to spell "Black hole" please use a dictionary.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the spelling of a word is best answered with a dictionary.  This is utterly trivial to answer.  There is nothing "interesting" about it at all.

Comment: Perhaps, as this asks "which spelling should be used **here**, this should be moved to meta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s a single word. Used to be double, but quickly became single.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redshift

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redshift

https://www.oed.com/dictionary/redshift_n?tab=factsheet#26403329

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=redshift%2C+red-shift&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3
(I’d curious about the diminishing number of mentions of “redshift” since 2000—not that “red-shift” has increased during the same period, on the contrary)

Comment: But then why does this editor and Quora's too redline it, as a misspelling? Wot, it's/they're out of date?

Comment: Scientific terms very often get redlined by non-scientific spell checkers. I've also had spell checkers ping on "email" because they think it should have a hyphen. Language evolves and programs react slowly.